# Using HTTPWebRequest for postdata...what am I missing here?

Tags: post, cookies, httpwebrequest, postdata

I've been designing a program that helps users navigate and use online dating sites.  Part of the program allows users to send a message through the program, but I'm having trouble with the website pof.com.

I've verified that the postData variable is turning out a string that perfectly matches what my browser would send.  Here is the code where I assume the problem lies:

```
    pofMessage = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(pofMessage)
    Dim postData As String = sendParameter1 & "=" & sendParameter1_Value & "&autologinid=" & autoLoginID & "&message_id=" & messageID & "&u=" & u & "&p_id=" & p_ID & "&receiver=" & receiver & "&profile_idb=" & profile_idb & "&usersendtob=" & usersendtob & "&i=" & i & "&v=" & v & "&subject=" & pofSubject & "&message=" & pofMessage & "&sendmessage=Send+Quick+Msg"
    Dim encoding As New UTF8Encoding
    Dim bytedata As Byte() = encoding.GetBytes(postData)
    'postData = "7512b8a8=b5818092d0d1d696329a2f6a8e9ef5b7&autologinid=vfnbrfzx4cptyhoimlojxs54&message_id=&u=Ca_Polo&p_id=40749839&reciever=janebrandy2000&profile_idb=40749839&usersendtob=44672906&i=18213689&v=13&subject=Hi&message=sorry...I+meant+my+great+grandmother.++She+was+a+very+sweet+person.&sendmessage=Send+Quick+Msg"

    Dim postReq As HttpWebRequest = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create("http://www.pof.com/sendmessage.aspx"), HttpWebRequest)
    postReq.Method = "POST"
    postReq.KeepAlive = True
    postReq.CookieContainer = loginCookie
    postReq.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    postReq.Referer = "http://www.pof.com/viewprofile.aspx?profile_id=" & profileAddressSend(arrayIndex)
    postReq.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:11.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/11.0"
    postReq.ContentLength = bytedata.Length
    MessageBox.Show(postData)
    Dim postReqStream As Stream = postReq.GetRequestStream()
    postReqStream.Write(bytedata, 0, bytedata.Length)
```

I don't know if this would be useful, but here is what live HTTP headers gave me:

```
--------------BEGIN HEADERS---------------------------

http://www.pof.com/sendmessage.aspx

POST /sendmessage.aspx HTTP/1.1
Host: www.pof.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:13.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/13.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
DNT: 1
Connection: keep-alive
Referer: http://www.pof.com/viewprofile.aspx?profile_id=40749839
Cookie: ft=Friday, May 04, 2012 10:56:08 PM; __utma=181982502.1869691959.1336197311.1339544889.1339562544.21; __utmz=181982502.1338435116.11.2.utmcsr=google|utmccn=(organic)|utmcmd=organic|utmctr=(not%20provided); usernameb=my_username; tmp_track=18213689; __utmv=181982502.|2=intent=want%20to%20date%20but%20nothing%20serious=1^3=age=35=1^4=Gender=Male%20United%20States=1; __gads=ID=b617d731de96c1fd:T=1336199229:S=ALNI_MaTMf9mj4CcziGfucCbsyfH-o2CdA; tbtext002=Dating%2CA; t_user_id=18213689; ASP.NET_SessionId=vfnbrfzx4cptyhoimlojxs54; __utmc=181982502; POFIMSession=634751342250621962; __utmb=181982502.4.10.1339562544; alogin=vfnbrfzx4cptyhoimlojxs54; mp_60ea1aa63a18cdb7ab1fb007106b9de3_mixpanel=%7B%22distinct_id%22%3A%20%22137d031c4821a4-050684bdf5e497-43534134-100200-137d031c4837d%22%2C%22%24initial_referrer%22%3A%20%22%24direct%22%2C%22%24initial_referring_domain%22%3A%20%22%24direct%22%7D
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 308
7512b8a8=b5818092d0d1d696329a2f6a8e9ef5b7&autologinid=vfnbrfzx4cptyhoimlojxs54&message_id=&u=my_username&p_id=40749839&reciever=janebrandy2000&profile_idb=40749839&usersendtob=44672906&i=18213689&v=13&subject=Hi&message=this+is+a+sample+message&sendmessage=Send+Quick+Msg
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Location: /inbox.aspx?messagesent=1&p_id=40749839&Guid=18213689&SID=vfnbrfzx4cptyhoimlojxs54#in
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Wed, 13 Jun 2012 04:44:32 GMT
Content-Length: 214

-----------------------END HEADERS---------------------
```

This is what I've verified (I think...unless I'm missing something): the postData is accurate.  The cookie I use works for navigating through the site (ie if I wanted to view my inbox, the cookie will allow me to do that.  If the cookie didn't work, I couldn't view my inbox).

What am I missing here?

Comment: You seem to know your stuff - I don't seen anything wrong with the code or http headers. If you haven't done it already, you might try using fiddler to get an exact copy of what your browser sends and compare that line-for-line.

Comment: Does content length match on fiddler and the one you create?